# Why NO_DATA_FOUND exception has a different behavior than others exceptions?

Tags: oracle, exception

I have this PL/SQL function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Test_FunctionNoDataFound RETURN NUMERIC AS
    var NUMERIC;
BEGIN
    SELECT val INTO var FROM table1 WHERE id = -1; -- Throw NO_DATA_FOUND
    RETURN 1;
END;
```

And I want to run this SQL statement:

```
SELECT Test_FunctionNoDataFound FROM dual;
```

Even if `Test_FunctionNoDataFound` throw an exception, my statement runs normally and the function returns `NULL` value.
But now, if `Test_FunctionNoDataFound` is defined as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Test_FunctionNoDataFound RETURN NUMERIC AS
    var NUMERIC;
BEGIN
    SELECT val INTO var FROM table1 WHERE id > 0; -- Throw TOO_MANY_ROWS
    RETURN 1;
END;
```

If I run the previous `SELECT` statement, this time, I get an exception.

**Why `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception has a different behavior than `TOO_MANY_ROWS`?

Is it the only exception with this kind of behavior?**

Comment: Tom Kyte explains it https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::p11_question_id:10321465390114

Comment: Thanks. I already read this post but I don't understand the notion of _exceptional condition_ he is talking about. I didn't find any reference of it in the official documentation.

Comment: It's Oracle. Many things are just the way they are because that's the way they are. Don't forget the Oracle DBMS has been around since 1979. That's almost 40 years!

Comment: @Colin'tHart It's the answer I was afraid of. So, it's just an undocumented behavior of Oracle and it only happens with `NO_DATA_FOUND`?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/appdev.920/a96624/07_errs.htm Note that SQLCODE is +100, while all other exceptions are negative... Maybe that's how the engine differentiates between them.

Comment: I think you need to mentally think of them as "informational messages from the RDBMS that require a course of action" rather than exceptions.

Comment: it comes down to the fact that NO_DATA_FOUND is not necessarily an error. Whilst retrieving data we WILL reach the end of our list and NO_DATA_FOUND is just the way that that EOL message is sent. TOO_MANY_ROWS on the other hand is and error condition that the developer should be trapping and handling/raising. The advice from @Philᵀᴹ is probably the best way to change your thinking about it.